# Exclude URL for Anonymous user in SharePoint 2013 Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

One of my SharePoint 2013 Site has been configured With Search and anonymous access.I would like configure search rules to exclude Search result URL for anonymous user alone.How to achieve this functionality..

Comment: Just a thought to create a query rule if the user name is not valid, remove search result from that site. Something like if {User.Title}<0 -Path:<siteURL> Let me know if you need a step-by-step screenshot

Comment: Just secure the pages you don't want anonymous users to see in search. Then ensure the authenticated users are in a group with at least view privileges.